# Saving GRAYSCALE .png image with cv2.imwrite() not working

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I've generated images by using `tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator` and I've plotted what I've generated using `matplotlib`, here are the results:

[image]

This is actually what I want saved on my file system, but for some reason whenever I try to write the image using `cv2.imwrite()` function I get this:

[image]

In some cases the image that is saved is completely blank (all pixels are white). Here is the code:

```
cnt = 0
for image, label in zip(augmented_images, labels):
  cnt += 1
  path = os.path.join(augmented_raw_images_train_dir,str(int(label[0])),"aug_"+str(cnt)+".png")
  cv2.imwrite(path, image[0])
```

Have in mind that image is a batch of size 1, so `image[0]` is actually a n-dim numpy array of size `(150, 150, 1)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely your pixel values from your data is in range [0.0, 1.0]. You should convert them to [0, 255] range before saving them via opencv.

```
cnt = 0
for image, label in zip(augmented_images, labels):
  cnt += 1
  path = os.path.join(augmented_raw_images_train_dir,str(int(label[0])),"aug_"+str(cnt)+".png")
  image_int = np.array(255*image[0], np.uint8)
  cv2.imwrite(path, image_int)
```

If values are in [-1, 1] range you can adjust accordingly.